Migrating to Spring Boot 3.4.0 - Deprecated OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration#applyDefaultSecurity
With Spring Boot 3.3.5, I had this
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration#applyDefaultSecurity is deprecated with Spring Boot 3.4.0.
     * @deprecated For removal in 2.0. Use
     * {@link HttpSecurity#with(SecurityConfigurerAdapter, Customizer)} and pass in
     * {@link OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer#authorizationServer()}.

To me, this description is somewhat unclear, so I replaced OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http) with the implementation of applyDefaultSecurity
        var authorizationServerConfigurer = OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.authorizationServer();

        http
                .securityMatcher(authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher())
                .with(authorizationServerConfigurer, Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated());

While tests are passing with this change, I feel doing this is not correct. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

They removed the Configuration in Spring Security Samples. I added an issue on the project. Maybe they provide an example soon.
I do it the same way as you do:
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer =
            OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.authorizationServer().oidc(Customizer.withDefaults()); // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http        
            .securityMatcher(authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher())
            .with(authorizationServerConfigurer, Customizer.withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                  new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"), new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)));
        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }


Is this an actual answer?
